# How to access local file system from WebKit browsers using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, filesystems, webkit

I am using WebKit to rendering my HTML pages. Now, say I am browsing the page, I select some text while reading and want to save/write down the selected text on my local file system. Is any way to access (read/write) local file system using WebKit?

In case of Firefox, I can access localfile using XPCOM, nsiFile. Can anyone suggest what I should use to do the same with WebKit?

Comment: possible duplicate of [EXE from JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3155231/exe-from-javascript)

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at the [File API](http://www.w3.org/TR/file-writer-api/). Support will depend on which flavor of Webkit you're using, but the nightlies should have some support.